# why "where" changing the original data type

Tags: c#

```
            CogoPointCollection COGOPointsCollection = civilAcitveDoc.CogoPoints;

            var cogoCollection2 = COGOPointsCollection.Where( p => 
                selectedPointGroup.ContainsPoint( ((CogoPoint)p.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead)).PointNumber ));
```

why cogoCollection2 become IEnumerableCogoPointCollection type not just CogoPointCollection type

Comment: Because the return type of `Where()` is `IEnumerable<T>`. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: It doesn't become that type. It should become `IEnumerable<CogoPoint>`, not `IEnumerable<CogoPointCollection>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ methods work on enumerations, and always yield an `IEnumerable<T>` of some kind.

If you want to convert back to the original collection type, you'd have to do that yourself in code. If CogoPointCollection has an appropriate constructor, for example, you could do this:

```
CogoPointCollection COGOPointsCollection = civilAcitveDoc.CogoPoints;

var cogoCollection2 = new CogoPointCollection
(
    COGOPointsCollection.Where
    (
        p => selectedPointGroup.ContainsPoint
        ( 
            ((CogoPoint)p.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead)).PointNumber 
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: i got error: 'CogoPointCollection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argumnet.

Comment: Please read carefully. ***If CogoPointCollection has an appropriate constructor**, for example, you could do this*. You did not post the code for CogoPointCollection so I cannot help you further with that,